# How do I access my ubuntu on cloud from a browser?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I just had a real scare and I thought I lost all my pictures. I had uploaded everything to ubuntu1 and a bit later thought my hard drive crashed. Is there a way to get ubuntu1 cloud files without a ubuntu computer?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your files at:

- http://one.ubuntu.com

Login, and then click on the "Files" tab.